# How should I structure a query to sort listings by best rating?

Tags: mysql

I have a table of listings and a table of reviews.  I would like to sort listings by best rating but the idea I have in mind has one problem... If I order by the average rating, a listing with an average of 5 stars but only has one review will appear higher on the list than a listing that has 500 reviews and an average of 4.5 stars.  How could I solve this problem if I have the following query?

```
SELECT
  l.listing_id, l.listing_title,
  COUNT(rev.review_id) AS total_reviews, (FLOOR(((SUM(rev.score) / COUNT(rev.review_id))) * 2) / 2) AS stars
FROM listings AS l
LEFT JOIN reviews AS rev ON l.listing_id = r.review_listing_id
GROUP BY l.listing_id
ORDER BY {what to order by}
```

Comment: I don't think this problem is solved in MySQL. You will find that a lot of rating systems won't publish an average rating until x number of reviews are submitted. For example: "This listing requires 5 more reviews before it can be rated" if often seen around the web.

Answer (score 0):

You will need some kind of formula for that.

Example from [imdb.com](http://imdb.com):

> weighted rating (WR) = (v ÷ (v+m)) × R + (m ÷ (v+m)) × C
>
> Where:
>
> R = average for the movie (mean) = (Rating) 
>   v = number of votes for the movie = (votes) 
>   m = minimum votes required to be listed in the Top 250 (currently 25,000) 
>  
>   C = the mean vote across the whole report

<s>So you could so that by:</s>

```
SELECT
    l.listing_id, l.listing_title,
    COUNT(r.review_id) AS total_reviews, 
    (FLOOR((AVG(rev.score) * 2) / 2) AS stars,
    (
        SELECT 
            AVG(FLOOR(AVG(rev.score) * 2) / 2)
        FROM 
            reviews AS r 
        INNER JOIN 
            listings AS l ON r.review_listing_id = l.listing_id
    ) as totalAvg,
    ((total_reviews / (total_reviews+5)) * stars + (5 / (total_reviews+5)) * totalAvg) AS wr
FROM 
    listings AS l
LEFT JOIN 
    reviews AS rev ON l.listing_id = r.review_listing_id
GROUP BY 
    l.listing_id
ORDER BY
    wr
```

**Edit:** query not correct

Comment: I saw that formula, but I didn't quite understand what they meant by their definition of the M variable... what if you don't care a minimum number of votes?  will this still include all listings?

Comment: @ShoeLace1291 If you don't have a minimum, just use `1`

Comment: @ShoeLace1291 or you can use your own formula based on what you find important.

Comment: Any idea why I would get the error "Unknown column total_reviews in field list"?